# MongoDB - Update different arrays simultaneously with update_many()

Tags: python, mongodb

First, some background.
I have a function in Python which consults an external API to retrieve some information associated with an ID. Such function takes as argument an ID and it returns a list of numbers (they correspond to some metadata associated with such ID).
For example, let us introduce in such function the IDs `{0001, 0002, 0003}`. Let's say that the function returns for each ID the following arrays:

```
0001 → [45,70,20]  
0002 → [20,10,30,45]  
0003 → [10,45]
```

My goal is to implement a collection which structures data as so:

```
{
    "_id":45,
    "list":[0001,0002,0003]
},
{
    "_id":70,
    "list":[0001]
},
{
    "_id":20,
    "list":[0001,0002]
},
{
    "_id":10,
    "list":[0002,0003]
},
{
    "_id":30,
    "list":[0002]
}
```

As it can be seen, I want my collection to index the information by the metadata itself. With this structure, the document with $_id "45" contains a list with all the IDs that have metadata 45 associated. This way I can retrieve with a single request to the collection all IDs mapped to a particular metadata value.
The class method in charge of inserting IDs and metadata in the collection is the following:

```
def add_entries(self,id,metadataVector):
    start = time.time()
    id=int(id)
    
    for data in metadataVector:
        self.SegmentDB.update_one(
            filter = {"_id":data},
            update = {"$addToSet":{"list":id}},
            upsert = True
        )


    end = time.time()
    duration = end-start
    return duration
```

**metadataVector** is the list which contains all metadata (integers) associated to a given ID (i.e.:`[45,70,20]`).
**id** is the ID associated to the metadata in metadataVector. (i.e.:0001).
This method currently iterates through the list and performs an operation for every element (every metadata) on the list. This method implements the collection I desire: it updates the document whose "_id" is a given metadata and adds to its corresponding list the ID from which such metadata originated (if such document doesn't exist yet, it inserts it - that's what upsert = true is all for).
However, this implementation ends up being somewhat slow on the long run. **metadataVector** usually has around 1000-3000 items for each ID (metainformation integers which can range in 800 - 23000000), and I have around 40000 IDs to analyze. As a result, the collection grows quickly. At the moment, I have around 3.2m documents in the collection (one specifically dedicated to each individual metadata integer). I would like to implement a faster solution; if possible, I would like to insert all metadata in one only DB request instead of calling an update for each item in **metadataVector** individually.
I tried this approach but it doesn't seem to work as I intended:

```
def add_entries(self,id,metadataVector):           
    start = time.time()                        
    id=int(id)                                 
                                                   
    self.SegmentDB.update_many(                
        filter={"_id": {"$in":metadataVector}},
        update={"$addToSet":{"list":id}},      
        upsert = True          
    )                                          
                                                   
        end = time.time()                          
        duration = end-start                       
        return duration
```

I tried using **update_many** (as it seemed the natural approach to tackle the problem) specifying a filter which, to my understanding, states *"any document whose _id is in **metadataVector**"*. In this way, all documents involved would add to the list the originating ID (or the document would be created if it didn't exist due to the Upsert condition) but instead the collection ends up being filled with documents containing a single element in the list and an ObjectId() _id.
[Picture showing the final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBwsM.png).

Is there a way to implement what I want? Should I restructure the DB differently all together?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: 3 million documents is not a particularly large number.

Comment: Good to know! Anyway, the insertion of all the metadata for a given ID (around 1000-3000 integers) in the database when it has a big amount of documents starts to be rather slow (6-8 seconds for the insertion, sometimes even way worse). I think my iterative approach (perform one update per metadata) is not the optimal way to tackle the insertion, if I could manage to convey the db all the information in one go and let the db itself insert all the information (instead of doing it myself individually, one metadata at a time), insertion times would lower (which is my goal)

Comment: I do not understand what your question is. This is not a site where someone designs a system for you. If you are saying your solution is slow, do you have it backed by adequate hardware (i.e. nvme ssds in a raid array) that provides multi-gb/s write speed?

Comment: @ppatus I am also having a similar problem, but looks like you can't do it, I am also trying like this     
for index, row in df.iterrows():
        coll.update_many(filter = {"_id": row["_id"]}, update = {"$set": {"new_col_2": row["new_col"]}}, upsert=True) please post an answer if you found the solution

Comment: @ppatus I am also having a similar problem, but looks like you can't do it, I am also trying like this, anyway adding bounty incase there is some solution! `for index, row in df.iterrows(): coll.update_many(filter = {"_id": row["_id"]}, update = {"$set": {"new_col_2": row["new_col"]}}, upsert=True)`

Comment: Why cant your function return a dictionary with key-values like this: `{ 45: [ 1, 2, 3], 10: [ 2, 3], `?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example, and it uses **Bulk Write** operations. Bulk operations submits multiple inserts, updates, deletes (can be a combination) as a single call to the database and returns a result. This is more efficient than multiple single calls to the database.

**Scenario 1:**

Input: `3 -> [10, 45]`

```
def some_fn(id):
    # id = 3; and after some process... returns a dictionary
    return { 10: 3, 45: 3, }
```

**Scenario 2:**

Input (as a list):

```
3 -> [10, 45]
1 -> [45, 70, 20]

def some_fn(ids):
    # ids are 1 and 3; and after some process... returns a dictionary
    return { 10: [ 3 ], 45: [ 3, 1 ], 20: [ 1 ], 70: [ 1 ] }
```

**Perform Bulk Write**

Now, perform the bulk operation on the database using the returned value from `some_fn`.

```
data = some_fn(id) # or some_fn(ids)

requests = []
for k, v in data.items():
    op = UpdateOne({ '_id': k }, { '$push': { 'list': { '$each': v }}}, upsert=True)
    requests.append(op)

result = db.collection.bulk_write(requests, ordered=False)
```

Note the `ordered=False` - this option is used for, again, better performance as writes can happen in parallel.

**References:**

- [collection.bulk_write](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=bulk#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write)